# Custom Delegates For UIViewController Having ContainerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates, uicontainerview

I hope all are doing well and enjoying happy coding life.

I want to use delegates of ChlidView in ParentView.

ChatHomeViewController(ParentView)

[image]

**ChatHomeViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ChatActionsViewController.h"

@interface     ChatHomeViewController:UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate, ChatActionsViewControllerDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableViewChatHome;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *cmdBackMenu;


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *containerViewActions;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *cmdShowActions;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewHeadin;

@end
```

**ChatHomeViewController.m**

```
@interface ChatHomeViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *tableData;

@end

@implementation ChatHomeViewController
@synthesize tableViewChatHome;
@synthesize cmdShowActions;
@synthesize containerViewActions;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];

[cmdShowActions addTarget:self action:@selector(displayChatActions) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[containerViewActions setHidden:YES];

}

-(void)displayChatActions{

ChatActionsViewController *chatActions = [[ChatActionsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChatActionsViewController" bundle:nil];
chatActions.delegate = self;

[containerViewActions setHidden:NO];
}

#pragma mark - ChatActions Delegates
-(void)creatNewChat:(NSString *)newChatOrGroup{

NSLog(@"creatNewChat:(NSString *)newChatOrGroup");
[containerViewActions setHidden:YES];

}
```

ChatActionsViewController(ChileView)

[image]

**ChatActionsViewController.h**
    #import

```
@protocol ChatActionsViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
-(void)creatNewChat: (NSString *)newChatOrGroup;

@end

@interface ChatActionsViewController : UIViewController

@property (assign,nonatomic) id<ChatActionsViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewBG1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewBG2;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *cmdCreatNewGroup;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *cmdCreatNewChat;

- (IBAction)actionNewChat:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)actionNewGroup:(id)sender;

@end
```

**ChatActionsViewController.m**

```
#import "ChatActionsViewController.h"

@interface ChatActionsViewController ()

@end

@implementation ChatActionsViewController
@synthesize viewBG1, viewBG2;
@synthesize cmdCreatNewChat, cmdCreatNewGroup;
@synthesize delegate;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[viewBG1 layer] setCornerRadius:4];
    [[viewBG1 layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor lightTextColor].CGColor];
    [[viewBG1 layer] setBorderWidth:1];
    viewBG1.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    viewBG1.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1);
    viewBG1.layer.shadowRadius = 3;
    viewBG1.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2;

    [[viewBG2 layer] setCornerRadius:4];
    [[viewBG2 layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor lightTextColor].CGColor];
    [[viewBG2 layer] setBorderWidth:1];
    viewBG2.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    viewBG2.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1);
    viewBG2.layer.shadowRadius = 3;
    viewBG2.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2;

}

- (IBAction)actionNewChat:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"actionNewChat");
    [[self delegate] creatNewChat:@"1"];
}

- (IBAction)actionNewGroup:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"actionNewGroup");
    [[self delegate] creatNewChat:@"2"];
}
@end
```

The issue I am facing is delegate is not working propoerly. Initially, the containerView is hidden. When user click **"+"** Button then containerView becomes visible.
I want delegate worked if I click on **New Chat** or **New Group** Buttons.

Please help me running this delegate.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ChatActionsViewController *chatActions = [[ChatActionsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChatActionsViewController" bundle:nil];
chatActions.delegate = self;
```

You create a new instance of the class but don't ever use it.

```
containerViewActions
```

This embedded view controller has *another* instance of the class that is loaded from the storyboard. You should give the **embed** segue an identifier in Interface builder and then use `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue 
                 sender:(id)sender;`

in the parent view controller. You can find the segue with `[segue identifier]` and store a pointer to the destination view controller from there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.